# Power BI Add rank or row number to column

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, rank, measure

Im trying to add just a simple rank numbering or row number to column but no luck.
I have a simple test table which consist of 2 columns - Name and Room number. I have attached Room Number to filter so it can be filtered. My goal is to add a number to resulted raws. Im using dax measure for this but no luck. This is my DAX measure code:

Visitor num = RANKX('myTab',CALCULATE(count('myTab'[Name])))

But it returns only 1 for each row[image]

[image]

[My PBIX file](https://fastupload.io/en/6hQC1D0FhFICRIA/file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the filter context:

Visitor num = RANKX(ALLSELECTED('myTab'),CALCULATE(MAX('myTab'[Name])))

[image]

Comment: Hi.  I've tried your code but the result is just the same as mine. In both cases without filter and with filter it shows just 1 in each  column

Comment: Can you paste you .pbix?

Comment: Sure https://fastupload.io/en/6hQC1D0FhFICRIA/file

Comment: I'll update my code for you now.

Comment: The only working code in the whole internet!. Yes its works now. Thanx a lot

Comment: Lol. Glad it's sorted.